# jquery event firing before knockout

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have the below table

```
<table id="users">
  <tbody data-bind="foreach: AllItems">                      
    <tr class="master">                      
      <td>                              
        <button data-bind="click:$root.removeItem">Remove</button>                               
      </td>                     
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I have a jquery event which listens for clicks on the tr

```
$("#users").on("click",".master", function (e) {    
    $(this).next("tr").toggle();
    $(this).find(".arrow").toggleClass("up");
});
```

I also have the knockout data-bind="click:$root.removeItem" event.

My issue is that the Jquery event fires before the knockoutevent and expands the next tr as it's programmed. I just want the knockout event to be fired when the button is clicked. Can someone please tell me how to do it.

Thanks

Comment: The solution is simple. Don't use jQuery *and* knockout to handle events and manipulate the DOM. Throw out the jQuery and use knockout for all DOM manipulation. Toggling classes is easily done with the `css` binding.

Answer (score 0):

The removeItem function can accept two parameters, where the object which is bound to clicked element and the event is sent. So it can look like this

```
self.removeItem = function(item, event){
    //DO what ever your removeItem function does

    // save clicked element to jquery obj
    var clickedRow = $(event.target);
    // do the same you did before in jquery event handler
    clickedRow.next("tr").toggle();
    clickedRow.find(".arrow").toggleClass("up");
}
```

HTML:

```
<button data-bind="click:$root.removeItem.bind()">Remove</button>
```